# Jenkins spikes up the the CPU usage to 100%

Tags: unix, jenkins, process

I have a jenkins master which has 3 docker slaves and 2 VM slaves. I have installed Jenkins as a service on RedHat linux. It is observed that, the CPU utilization goes upto 100% sometimes and thereby I have to reboot the box. When i check the processes, I can see that there is a main master jenkins process and several other child jenkins processes(which are an exact replica of the master process) are hung and are causing the spike(Confirmed this through new relic).

I am trying to reproduce this issue, however have been unsuccessful in the same.

Below are my queries:

1. I know the previous process id, can I get some logs or dumps related to it post the server restart?
2. Is there a better approach to trouble shoot this, so that I can narrow down on the issue?

At this point I am unable to understand where are these child processes getting spawned from and how can I find the culprit.